# Why extrudeGeometry produce wrong depth or height?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I want to make my 2D into 3D using extrudeGeometry. However the height is not what I am expeted. The mesh has a very high z or depth.
Here is my code :

```
const geoPoints = [];

geoPoints.push(new THREE.Vector2(1, 1));
geoPoints.push(new THREE.Vector2(-1, 1));
geoPoints.push(new THREE.Vector2(-1, -1));
geoPoints.push(new THREE.Vector2(1, -1));

const geoPointsShape = new THREE.Shape(geoPoints);
const califorGeo = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(californiaShape);
const extrudeSettings = {
  steps: 1,
  depth: 0.1,
  bevelEnabled: false,
};

const extrude = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(geoPointsShape, extrudeSettings);

const calMesh = new THREE.Mesh(extrude, globalMaterial);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by:

```
  const extrudeSettings = {
      amount: 1,
      bevelEnabled: false,
    };
```

Comment: It seems you are using an outdated version of `three.js`. In recent versions, `amount` has been renamed to `depth`.